# php javascript basic line

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Im trying to edit a line of code in a chat script. I know nothing about ajax or javascript I just know basic php.

The line i want to edit is in a  tag. `xmlhttp.responseText` outputs what's in chat.txt and puts it in the 'chatwindow' element. I just want it to display the date at the bottom of when chat.txt was last modified.

The original line is:

```
document.getElementById("chatwindow").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

and I want to do this:

```
document.getElementById("chatwindow").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText + date("F d Y H:i:s.", filectime("chat.txt"));
```

Could someone correct the syntax of my line?

Comment: Your code is JavaScipt, not PHP. Is the `document.getElementById` call being created by PHP? If so, post the surrounding PHP code.

Comment: sorry, updated. if i do `innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText + "test";` it shows "test" after it, so I just need to know how to add a date there of the file modified.

Comment: You misunderstand me. Please post what is inside `<?php ?>` tags in your PHP file. You're attempting to combine PHP and JS function calls, which does not work, so we need to see what the rest of your PHP looks like.

Comment: You could create a php file that echos out the contents of chat.txt with the modified date to the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = '<?php echo date("F d Y H:i:s.", filectime("chat.txt")); ?>';
document.getElementById("chatwindow").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText + ' - ' + date;
```

Comment: thanks, ive done that, but for some reason it's not updating the date as it is the chat content :/

Comment: Have you got a link we can see? Is the data echoed in the source code correctly?

Comment: is there anywhere i can post my chat.php page code? its 130 lines.